# How do you "migrate" to node auto provisioning?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Using GKE I currently have one managed node pool everything is on.

I can enable auto node provisioning but it's not clear to me from the docs what will happen.

If I enable it will my node pool be destroyed and replaced with an auto provisioned one? Will it require me to update all of all my apps with resource requests and a selector for them to use node auto provisioning?

I currently to not have any resource requests set for any apps.

Is it possible to gradually move apps off the node pool to auto provisioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your questions:

If I enable it will my node pool be destroyed and replaced with an auto provisioned one?

The current nodes will be updated with the new feature of  Node auto provisioning  so you  could suffer some drops while the cluster is updated to use the Node Auto provisioning; however, your workload will remain the same.  So once the cluster finishes configuring your Node [auto provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) future, your cluster will be able to  create new  node pools that are sized to meet demand and will be deleted automatically once the demand decreases.

Will it require me to update all of my apps with resource requests and a selector for them to use node auto provisioning?

No. You will only need to set the limit resources that will apply to all the clusters and that will trigger the autoprosionig if are overpassed, like in the following example:

```
gcloud container clusters update your-cluster \
    --enable-autoprovisioning \
    --min-cpu 1 \
    --min-memory 3 \
    --max-cpu 55 \
    --max-memory 170
```

Or you can configure the Auto provisioning defaults that are detailed in this [link](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#defaults).

Is it possible to gradually move apps off the node pool to auto provisioning?

You can create a new cluster with new features like auto scaling or  an [autopilot cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) in your same region. to expose your latest application release,  this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/deploy-app-gke)  could help you to create this new environment to production.

Comment: I'm still not clear on this. I enabled auto node provisioning on my cluster and it seems like nothing happened. My managed node pool is still there and when I deploy apps are deployed to that node pool. According to the docs I need to enable auto-node provisioning on any existing node pools if I want them to be auto-provisioned (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#mark_node_auto-provisioned). So what happened when I enabled it? Can I have a managed and auto-provisioned node pool on the same cluster?

Comment: @red888  Once the auto-provisioniong feature is enabled, it tells your GKE cluster that it can create and delete nodes automatically based on your application resources demand. This feature works with cluster [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) and can extend node pools automatically, but if your application is working under limits that were set before, there will be no need to resize the nodes in your cluster.

Comment: still not clear on this. I have my existing managed node pool. I enabled auto provisioning. I found that deploys went to my managed node pool. But then to test I specified memory requirements that could not be satisfied by it. I found when I did that it created a new node pool. so will gke leave my existing managed node pool alone? it is a supported config to have both managed and auto-provisioned node pools on the same cluster?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to you your doubts @red888:

so will gke leave my existing managed node pool alone?
Answer: Yes, it is a normal behavior when you enable auto provisioning to your current cluster so new node pools are created and deleted automatically.

it is a supported config to have both managed and auto-provisioned node pools on the same cluster?
Answer:Yes, you can configure a new nodepool in your cluster without node auto-provisioning enabled.